# How to make ESLint include local files?

Tags: javascript, html, eslint

I have a website with simple HTML but lots of javascript code. For that I am trying to use ESLint for the first time.

My html looks like this:

```
<html>
    . . .
    <body>
        . . .
        <script src="js/someLib.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In someLib.js there is a variable "myLibVar" that I use in main.js. It causes this error :

> ```
> 'myLibVar' is not defined. (no-undef)
> ```

It is not a node.js app, so I don't use require funtion.
How can I make ESLint to include someLib.js and prevent those no-undef errors?

Note: I am using VS code to develop code and someLib.js is not one of the popular libraries.

Comment: Have you tried something like /* global myLibVar */ at the top of your `main.js`?

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like `/* global myLibVar */` at the top of your `main.js`?